# Django app throws MigrationSchemaMissing when migrating to heroku MySQL ClearDB

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

So I have built a simple app using MySQL instead of SQlite and everything migrates nicely when I deploy on localhost, the localhost DB settings look like this:

```
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
#         'NAME': 'news',
#         'USER': 'myname',
#         'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
#         'HOST': 'localhost',   
#         'PORT': '',
#
#     }
# }
```

But I change the settings to the following for deploying to heroku using the ClearDB addon:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'heroku_db_dbname',
    'USER': 'heroku_db_username',
    'PASSWORD': 'heroku_db_password',
    'HOST': 'us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net',
    'PORT': '3306',

}
```

}

With heroku_db_name, heroku_db_username and heroku_db_password being the actual values from heroku obviously.

The app deploys just fine minus the DB and I can makemigrations with no issues but once I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get a MigrationSchemaMissing exception, more specifically:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: 
Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1064, "You have an error
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
 version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1"))
```

I'm not sure how there can be a syntax error since all the SQL is generated by django and all of it works fine on my local machine. I can post the entire error trace if that would be more helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: try granting the access to the schema - 
grant usage on schema public to public; grant create on schema public to public;

Comment: Side note: instead of hard-coding your database settings, consider using something like [`dj-database-url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) or [`django-heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku) to pull your database connection information from the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, I have MySQL server 5.5, It seems like it is not supported by Django 2.1

So I downgrade to Django 2.0:

```
pip install Django==2.0.0 -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple
```

I found the idea here: https://www.codetw.com/clxcyl.html